# How to evenly space 3 select box's inline using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to space 3x select box's evenly so they are all the same width but all 3x combined need to span the full length of the container under the search bar so everything lines up.

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxjyaP)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Seach here..." />
      </div>
      <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control make-me-wider">
                <option>City</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
            <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control make-me-wider">
                <option>Type</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
              <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control make-me-wider">
                <option>Category</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
       </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
form {
   margin-top: 30px;
}

.make-me-wider {
  width: 33%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the div class="form-group" needs to be closed after every select. Also parent div class="form-inline" needs a class row and every div around the select having class="form-group" needs a class col-xs-4. here is a working sample of code

JSFillde URL: http://jsfiddle.net/r2qronjm/1/

```css
form {
   margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Seach here..." />
      </div>
      <div class="form-inline row">
          <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>City</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
       </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Type</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
       </div>
              <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Category</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
       </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: This is better solution I have to admit (for bootstrap compliance). Don't forget to add a `style="width:100%"` for every select

Comment: Yup, I try using just Divs and bootstrap classes to make it RWD compliant in the future. Also, a select withing a div having class="form-control" should automatically have width set to 100%. But adding it again makes no harm :) added the changes in JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/r2qronjm/4/

Answer (score 0):

Just use a table inside your form-group and add a `width:100%` for every `select`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogdJQa

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Seach here..." />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <table cellpading="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select class="form-control" style="width:100%">
              <option>City</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
              <select class="form-control"  style="width:100%">
                <option>Type</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
              </select>
          </td>
          <td>
              <select class="form-control"  style="width:100%">
                <option>Category</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
              </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
</form>
```